# How to include image from url in pdf document

Tags: graphics, urls

For example, if I want to add this image from url

http://www.qqxxzx.com/images/profile-pics/profile-pics-16.jpg

in my pdf, what do I have to do?

I have tried several solutions with `href`. For example this one

```
\begin{figure}%[2]
    \centering
    \href{http://www.qqxxzx.com/images/profile-pics/profile-pics-16.jpg}{\includegraphics{profile-pics-16.jpg}}

\end{figure}
```

but nothing is working. I always get this error

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `profile-pics-16.jpg' not found. See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.57 ...pg}{\includegraphics{profile-pics-16.jpg}}
```

Comment: Just download it manually and put it somewhere where `latex` can find it.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine with `pdflatex` as long as you load the following two packages:`\usepackage{graphicx}` and 
`\usepackage{hyperref}`.  If that does not resolve your issue, please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: if latex did not find it then presumably you saved the file in the wrong place (same folder as your document is the easiest place)

Comment: I used the same code but this is not working and giving error, so its not duplicate

Comment: @user1478137: You are probably not running with the `--shell-escape` flag on.

Answer (score 6):

The shell escape feature (`\write18`) can be used to call external programs during the compilation. The following example first checks, if the file is present. If it is missing, then it calls `wget` to download the file if `pdflatex` was called with enabled shell escape feature, e.g. via option `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` (MiKTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \IfFileExists{profile-pics-16.jpg}{%
  }{%
    \immediate\write18{%
      wget http://www.qqxxzx.com/images/profile-pics/profile-pics-16.jpg%
    }%
  }
  \includegraphics{profile-pics-16.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In case of LuaTeX, shell escape is not necessary, because the downloading can be done by library `luasocket`.

The following example defines macro `\Download`, which takes the file name and the URL. If LuaTeX is detected, the downloading is handled in Lua. Otherwise shell escape is needed. For convenience, the file name is stored in macro `\DownloadFile` for the later use in `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
  \directlua{
    tex.enableprimitives('', {'luaescapestring'})
  }
  \newcommand*{\Download}[2]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    }{%
      \directlua{
        local io = require('io')
        local http = require('socket.http')
        local ltn12 = require('ltn12')
        local file_name = '\luaescapestring{#1}'
        local url = '\luaescapestring{#2}'
        texio.write_nl('Downloading: ' .. file_name)
        texio.write_nl('')
        http.request{
          url=url,
          sink=ltn12.sink.file(io.open(file_name, 'w'))
        }
      }%
    }%
    \edef\DownloadFile{#1}%
  }
\else
  \newcommand*{\Download}[2]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    }{%
      \immediate\write18{%
        wget -O "#2" "#1"%
      }%
    }%
    \edef\DownloadFile{#1}%
  }%
\fi

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \Download{profile-pics-16.jpg}{%
      http://www.qqxxzx.com/images/profile-pics/profile-pics-16.jpg%
    }
    \includegraphics{\DownloadFile}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Caution: The code does not check for any download errors.

Comment: For a general solution it would be better to use `shellesc`'s `\ShellEscape` macro. Newer versions of `luatex` no longer support `\write18`.

Comment: @Josef In LuaTeX the download can be directly managed in Lua, no need for shell escape here, see the updated answer.